# Jquery hover popup a div

Tags: jquery

Im using this Jquery to popup a div

```
        <script type="text/javascript">


         $(function () {
        $('.bubbleInfo2').each(function () {
            var distance = 10;
            var time = 250;
            var hideDelay = 500;

            var hideDelayTimer = null;

            var beingShown = false;
            var shown = false;
            var trigger = $('.trigger2', this);
            var info = $('.popup2', this).css('opacity', 0);


            $([trigger.get(0), info.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {
                if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                if (beingShown || shown) {
                    // don't trigger the animation again
                    return;
                } else {
                    // reset position of info box
                    beingShown = true;

                    info.css({
                        top: 40,
                        left: -160,
                        display: 'block'
                    }).animate({
                        top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                        opacity: 1
                    }, time, 'swing', function () {
                        beingShown = false;
                        shown = true;
                    });
                }

                return false;
            }).mouseout(function () {
                if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    hideDelayTimer = null;
                    info.animate({
                        top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                        opacity: 0
                    }, time, 'swing', function () {
                        shown = false;
                        info.css('display', 'none');
                    });

                }, hideDelay);

                return false;
            });
        });
    });

    //-->
       </script>
```

it's working well but i need to change in a way to be able to call it in a function and to pass the parameters because im using it several time on the page.In way to don;t have it many times on the page

that i would call it in something similar to this :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".bubbleInfo2").BubleFunction(....parameters to be passed

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function callthisfunction() {
    $(".bubbleInfo2").BubleFunction(....parameters to be passed

}
```

Comment: In this function the "bubbleInfo2" would be another name how to mention it in the function?

Comment: just create a function in Javascript. and called it where u want

Comment: would you give me an example please cause i need it urgently and it isn' t working with me

Answer (score 0):

if you want that, you need to make jquery plugin,
but it is simple
check out
http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial

Comment: how the jquery should be written in a way to be able to call it just by changing the id any idea?